# ArcGIS Feature Layer exceeds limit

Tags: arcgis

I'm new to ArcGIS.
I've been using it to publish a Roads Layer service on our ArcGIS server.
Everything seems to be working whenever I upload a Feature Class of a small area as a service. The roads appear on my web app, and everyone is happy.
Now, the service should support the entire world. So for starters, I tried uploading a feature class of California as a service. 
The Problem is that roads are loaded randomly instead of whatever is currently in my view. That way, I exceed the limit of features the server returns, and there are huge chunks of areas without roads.

After a crazy amount of researching, I've found how to Query for a specific area to load. Esri's documentation was not very helpful in this regard. Unfortunately, Roads are still loaded randomly in addition to the area requested. How do I load only the areas I query?
I'm using a service I uploaded using ArcMap 10.6 to ArcGIS Server.
Here is the relevant code in Javascript:

```
        this.layer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: this.featureServiceUrl,
        renderer: renderer,
        outFields: ["*"],
        elevationInfo: {
            mode: "on-the-ground"
        },
        refreshInterval: 0.1
    });
```

Creating a query for distance 1000:

```
        this.props.map.add(this.layer);
    // Get a query object for the layer's current configuration
    const queryParams = this.layer.createQuery();
    queryParams.geometryType = "point";
    // set a geometry for filtering features by a region of interest
    queryParams.geometry = new Point({
        x: -117.19477,
        y: 32.81452,
        z: 0
    });
    queryParams.distance = 1000;
    let results = await this.layer.queryFeatures(queryParams);
    await this.layer.applyEdits({
        updateFeatures: results.features
    });
    this.layer.refresh();
```

I think I'm missing something tiny but crucial.
If you need any other information to answer this question, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:
In ArcGIS Javascript  v4.9, When creating the FeatureLayer Object, this property should be added:

```
definitionExpression: [query object]
```

for example:

```
        this.layer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: this.featureServiceUrl,
        renderer: renderer,
        outFields: ["*"],
        elevationInfo: {
            mode: "on-the-ground"
        },
        definitionExpression: this.props.features_query
    });
```

Here's a reference to the API: [ArcGIS API Documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#definitionExpression).